# 2000 Toyota Tacoma - Won't start and it isn't the battery

Tags: toyota, starting, ignition, tacoma

2000 Toyota Tacoma
When I put the key in it just turns and won't start. It isn't the battery. It seems like it isn't catching for it to start. Could I need a new key or ignition switch?

Comment: do lights and radio come on?

Comment: When you say it turns, do you mean it cranks but doesn't start?

Answer (score 2):

As in the other answers, first check if you are or not getting power to those things that gets serviced when you turn the key. If you have a flat dead scenario here, then you need to check the ignition key.

If you get these loads working (lights, radio, etc) and if the starter doesn't turn, check starter fuse, starter relay and starter exciter wire to its solenoid.

If the starter turns but the car won't start, check you have gas in the tank :) If you have gas in the tank, then you need to route an electrical test from spark plugs all the way to coil. Have spark? Then it is the gas not coming in. No spark? Check wire, no spark? Check coil to distributor spark, no spark then check volts into coil. No volts, then the wire to coil is fault. Volts into coil but no spark at its end? Coil is bad. No spark at end of wire from coil to distributor? Wire is bad, etc.

Fastest way is: put new sparks, put new ignition wires and test. The engine is not starting...electrical or gas fault. Check for sparks, check for gas coming in.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible the issue is at the ignition switch.  The best way to test will be with a schematic and a test light to see that the ignition switch is getting voltage in, but is not putting voltage out when the key is turned.  If the ignition switch does put out voltage, follow it down the line to the starter relay, and the starter.  Also be sure to check any fuses.

If you do need to replace the ignition switch, you may need to get a set of security bits to remove parts of the steering column/ignition.